# Laravel Eloquent: eager loading of multiple nested relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

What laravel says:

```
$books = App\Book::with('author.contacts')->get();
```

What I need is something like this

```
$books = App\Book::with('author[contacts,publishers]')->get();
```

where we eager load multiple relationships within a relationship.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can do

```
 $books = App\Book::with('author.contacts','author.publishers')->get();
```

Comment: just to add, it will fetch the corresponding author data as well ofcourse.

Comment: Follow-up: I have a much more complex model and want to return a single collection, but like the original poster, wish I could use multiple nested relationships at a lower child level like `$event = event::with(['streams.experiences.selectors.['digitalprops.frames','filters']','streams.datacaptures'])->find($eventcode);`

Comment: @Todd How do you execute this code in Laravel? 
`$event = event::with(['streams.experiences.selectors.['digitalprops.frames','filters']','streams.datacaptures'])->find($eventcode);`. 

It shouldn't work...!

Comment: Right @tisuchi -- I said I *WISH* I could... sorry for the confusion.

Comment: does author is table name or what?

Comment: @msbomrel, author is a relationship method in the Book class

Answer (score 51):

Laravel documentation on [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) recommends listing the relationships in an array as follows:

```
$books = App\Book::with(['author.contacts', 'author.publishers'])->get();
```

You can have as many relationships as desired. You can also specify which columns should be included for a relationship like this:

```
//only id, name and email will be returned for author
//id must always be included
$books = App\Book::with(['author: id, name, email', 'author.contacts', 'author.publishers'])->get();
```

You may also add constrains as follows:

```
$books = App\Book::with(['author: id, name, email', 'author.contacts' => function ($query) {
                                          $query->where('address', 'like', '%city%');
                                     }, 'author.publishers'])->get();
```

Comment: This is the best overview how to eager load efficiently!

Comment: This looks amazing! Thanks for your input!

Comment: Honestly! This is WAY better than Laravel's documentation.

Answer (score 11):

So, now you can try

```
$books = App\Book::with(['author' => function($author){
     $author->with(['contacts', 'publishers'])->get();
}])->get();
```

Comment: I think that `->get()` is not needed at all within the closure

Answer (score 5):

From Laravel 9, the neatest way is the nested array :

```
$books = App\Book::with(['author' => [
             'contacts',
             'publishers'
         ])->get();
```

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading)

Answer (score 1):

When eager load nested relationships and we want to select just some columns and not all using `relationship:id,name`, always include the foreign key to the nested models, else they won't load at all.

Fort example, we have *orders* that have *identities* that have *addresses*.

This will not load the address:

```php
User::orders()
    ->with('identity:id,name', 'identity.address:id,street')
```

This will load the address because we have supplied the `address_id` foreign key:

```php
User::orders()
    ->with('identity:id,address_id,name', 'identity.address:id,street')
```