# Fetch news from specific category along with each news writer in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I have following function in Category model:

```
public function news(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(News::class,'news_categories','category_id','news_id');
}

public function writer(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(NewsAuthor::class,'news_authors','news_id','user_id');
}

public static function getNewsByCategory($id, $limit){
    return Category::where('id', $id)->has('news')
      ->with(['news' => function($q) use(&$limit) {
         $q->latest()->limit($limit);
      }])->first();
}
```

to fetch news by Category id, now, I also want to fetch news writer which is in the news_author table.

How can I get news author with my function `getNewsByCategory`?

Answer (score 0):

In News Modal add $with

```
protected $with = ['writers'];

public function writers(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(NewsAuthor::class,'news_authors','news_id','user_id');
}

// you can get writers for each new
foreach($category->news as $new) {
  $wirters = $new->writers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not just to add the `writer` relation inside the `with([ ... ])` according to [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

```
public static function getNewsByCategory($id, $limit){
    return Category::where('id', $id)->has('news')
      ->with(['news' => function($q) use(&$limit) {
         $q->latest()->limit($limit);
      }, 'writer'])->first();
}
```

Check [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53205641/3256489)